# swift finding match between string arrays

Tags: arrays, swift

I m kind of new in functional programming
If I have 2 arrays of strings, is there a way using map, filter and zip to return the matching values ?
I know a dirty way to do it, by iterating in each array and comapring the values to find matches but there must be a clean way to do it.

so var example i have the following arrays :

array1 = ["max","julie","helmut","igor"]
array2 = ["sophie","igor"]

and I would like to retrieve "igor" as a value

another thing, if there s more than one match, witch in my case is not possible, I would like to know how to return a string of matches (just for my own understanding)

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: What here is *functional programming*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Set` has a `intersect` method which returns the values that exist in the set and any `SequenceType`. I'm not sure if this is "functional" but it's certainly not "dirty".

```
let array1 = ["max","julie","helmut","igor"]
let array2 = ["sophie","igor","helmut"]

let common = Set(array1).intersect(array2)
print(common) //["igor", "helmut"]
```

Comment: That s why I love internet, I love you also

Comment: This will have runtime of O(len(array1)) for constructing the set + O(len(array2)) for `intersect()`. This will be much faster than O(len(array1)) for `filter` + O(len(array2) * len(array2)) for `contains`. This is a great trade if you can afford disregarding duplicates and can spare some extra memory.

Comment: nice, I was just wondering what was faster and testing both approaches, my arrays are HUGE, thanks for clearing this out for me

Comment: Added a generic version of this to my answer

Answer (score 3):

Something I whipped up quick. Should work for anything adhering to Equatable (such as a String):

```
func getMatches<T: Equatable>(firstArray: [T], secondArray: [T]) -> [T] {
    return firstArray.filter({secondArray.contains($0)})
}
```

Alternately, this is a generic version of [Kevin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35785863/1852164)

```
func getMatches<T: Equatable>(firstArray: [T], secondArray: [T]) -> Set<T> {
    return Set(firstArray).intersect(secondArray)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for your purposes:

```
let array1 = ["max","julie","helmut","igor"]
let array2 = ["sophie","igor"]

let arrayOfMatches = array1.filter { array2.contains($0) }
print(arrayOfMatches)
```

Let me know if you need anything more explained.
This is the shortest way to write this kind of statement.
Essentially filter needs to return a boolean that determines whether or not to keep the value over which it is iterating.

Comment: tks :) it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
let both = array1.filter{ array2.contains($0) }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alternative [PEEJWEEJ's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35785791/swift-finding-match-between-string-arrays/35785889#35785889)

If you return value `[T]` instead of `Set<T>`, try this. (T must conform to hashable)

```
func getMatches<T: Hashable>(firstArray: [T], secondArray: [T]) -> [T] {
    return Array(Set(firstArray).intersect(secondArray))
}
```

Comment: On a more serious note, will the returned array have an expected ordering? jc.

Comment: Sorry...! I fixed typo.